# MKSlidingTableViewCell not supports ASyncDisplayKit

Tags: ios, swift, smooth-scrolling, asyncdisplaykit

We are using Initially `UITableView` with `MKSlidingTableViewCell` now i facing the issue with scrolling. To overcome this i choose `ASyncDisplayKit`(AS tableview)

But these two(`MKSlidingTableViewCell`, `ASCellNodeBlock`) are not working in the same cell.

Can anyone please suggest me.

While using ASTableView:

func tableView(tableView: ASTableView, nodeForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ASCellNode {

```
     let post = postData[indexPath.row];

     let cell = UserProfileCell(currentPostData: post, index: indexPath.row, commentsOpenedIndex: openedCommentIndex);

     if post.post_type == "post"{

     cell.userInteractionEnabled = true;
     cell.cellDelegate = self;
     cell.FullPicDelegate = self;
     let height = cell.configureCell(post, index: indexPath.row, commentsOpenedIndex: openedCommentIndex);
     // let height = cell.configureCell(post, index: indexPath.row, commentsOpenedIndex: indexPath.row);
     heights[indexPath] = height;

     return { cell; }()

     }

    return { cell; }()

     }
```

While using MKSlidingTableView

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
     let post = postData[indexPath.row];
     if post.post_type == "post"{
     let cell = UserProfileCell();
     cell.userInteractionEnabled = true;
     cell.cellDelegate = self;
     cell.FullPicDelegate = self;
     let height = cell.configureCell(post, index: indexPath.row, commentsOpenedIndex: openedCommentIndex);
     // let height = cell.configureCell(post, index: indexPath.row, commentsOpenedIndex: indexPath.row);
     heights[indexPath] = height;

     // return cell;

     let container = MKSlidingTableViewCell();
     let backgroundCell = OptionsViewHomeEvents();
     backgroundCell.indexPath = indexPath
     backgroundCell.type = OptionsViewType.HomePosts;
     backgroundCell.reference = self;

     container.drawerView = backgroundCell;
     container.foregroundView = cell;

     container.delegate = self;

     container.drawerRevealAmount = OptionsDrawerWidth.HomePosts;
     if(APIHelper.logged_user_id  != post.user_id){
     container.drawerRevealAmount = 0;
     }

     return container;
     }

     }
```

Comment: Can you show some code? How did you integrate this two?

Comment: Thankyou for your reply Please see the attached screenshots above newly i added.

Screen1  image code was related ASTableView

screentwo image code was related ASyncDevelopment Kit

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots. There is option in the editor to format your text as code.

Comment: Please, i added code now